# combining three separate 3D graphs into one plot R

Tags: r, plotly

I have the following code

```
figfactor1<- plot_ly(X15a, x=~xplot,y=~yplot*-1,z=(~zplot*-1),
                  type="scatter3d",mode="markers",
                  marker=list(color=~vectorM,colorscale='Greys',
                  showscale=TRUE,colorbar=list(title="factor"),
                  cmin=0,cmax=1.2,
                  line=list(width=2,color='DarkSlateGrey')))
figfactor2<- plot_ly(X15b, x=~xplot,y=~yplot*-1,z=(~zplot*-1),
                  type="scatter3d",mode="markers",
                  marker=list(color=~vectorM,colorscale='Greys',
                  showscale=TRUE,colorbar=list(title="factor"),
                  cmin=0,cmax=1.2,
                  line=list(width=2,color='DarkSlateGrey')))
figfactor3<- plot_ly(X15c, x=~xplot,y=~yplot*-1,z=(~zplot*-1),
                  type="scatter3d",mode="markers",
                  marker=list(color=~vectorM,colorscale='Greys',
                  showscale=TRUE,colorbar=list(title="factor"),
                  cmin=0,cmax=1.2,
                  line=list(width=2,color='DarkSlateGrey')))
        
scene<-list(xaxis = list(title = 'x-value [mm]',range=c(-40,40),dtick=20,tickwidth=1),
            yaxis = list(title = 'y-value [mm]',range=c(0,200),dtick=20,tickwidth=1), 
            zaxis = list(title = 'z-value [mm]',range=c(0,150),dtick=20,tickwidth=1),
            camera=list(eye=list(x=2.1,y=0.3,z=0.6)))
                       
fig1 <- figfactor1 %>% layout( title="Volume category '0-1 cc'",scene=scene)
fig2 <- figfactor2 %>% layout( title="Volume category '1-10 cc'",scene=scene)
fig3 <- figfactor3 %>% layout( title="Volume category '>10 cc'",scene=scene)
```

How can I combine these three plots , with only 1 colorbar on the right-side of the three plots and with a title "Factor dicplacement". I would like to obtain the picture as shown below, Currently I am only getting three seperate pictures.

[image]

Comment: Your example isn't reproducible. Please share the output of `dput(X15a)` or `dput(head(X15a))` with us. Same for `X15b` and `X15c`.

Comment: The data X15a contains the x,y,z coordinates (column xplot, yplot and zplot) of each marker and a value between 0-1.5 for each coordinate point (in a column with name vectorM).  X15a contains the data one group of data points, X15b and X15c have the data of two other groups, but have the same column names. I added a figure to original question , this is the plot that I would like to obtain